# The $α$ Variable In $Ccos(ωt-α)$ in the Context of a Simple Circuit Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, electromagnetism

I've come across a circuit differential equation problem that I'm frustratingly close to solving:

"For a circuit described with the equation $I' + 10I = 30cos60t + 40sin60t$,  write the steady periodic solution in the form $I(t) = Ccos(ωt-α)$"

---

Through solving a differential equation, I found values $A=-21/37$, $B=-22/37$. So we have:

$C = \sqrt{A^2+B^2} = 0.82$ (This is correct)

$ω = 60$ (This is correct)

$α = tan^{-1}(\frac{B}{A})$ (for $0<α<\pi$) $ = 0.8$

The last expression is NOT correct; according to my key the true answer is $α = \pi $ MINUS $0.8$. Why would this need to be done? $0.8$ is already between $0$ and $\pi$, and I don't know of any other condition that would require you to modify $α$'s value in this way. Can anyone point out what I'm missing with this?

Comment: All trigonometric functions are periodic and therefore the inverses (arcus functions) need to pick a branch of which angles to give back because multiple angles can often give the same tans cos sins et.c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B$ and $A$ are really $x$ and $y$ coordinates.  Since both are negative in 
your problem, you're in the 3rd Quadrant.  That makes $\alpha = \pi+.08$.  Then since you need an angle between $0$ and $\pi$, we just note that $\cos(\pi+0.8) = \cos(\pi -0.8)$ to move the angle to the 2nd Quadrant.